# Issue on Google App Engine GAE: Unable to lock table schema_version

Tags: google-app-engine, flyway, google-cloud-sql

We are on GAE with Cloud SQL. Everything works great on the local dev server. We are using the AppEngineDriver with a static connection string. The connection is good in the production environment as Flyway was able to create the schema_version table.

But then we get an error that it's not able to lock said table. The table is empty. We have 3 migrations and none have been executed.

We launch the migration at the time Spring creates the DataSource bean, in Java config style.

Here's the stack trace.

Many thanks!

Update 1: I have added a relevant secondary stack trace at the end of the first one.

com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to lock table `ourschema`.`schema_version`:
java.sql.SQLException: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.newSqlException(Exceptions.java:219)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.check(SqlProtoClient.java:198)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.executeSql(SqlProtoClient.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.executeSql(SqlProtoClient.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.executeSql(Connection.java:528)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeSqlImpl(PreparedStatement.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Statement.executeImpl(Statement.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:122)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:214)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.mysql.MySQLTable.doLock(MySQLTable.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.Table.lock(Table.java:254)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:121)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:140)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:54)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:137)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:862)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:815)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1177)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:815)
    at com.ourapplication.pilote.persistence.FlywayMigrationDataSourceInitializer.postInitialize(FlywayMigrationDataSourceInitializer.java:23)
    at com.ourapplication.pilote.persistence.PersistenceConfiguration.initializeDataSource(PersistenceConfiguration.java:188)
    at com.ourapplication.pilote.persistence.PersistenceConfiguration.dataSource(PersistenceConfiguration.java:175)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.newSqlException(Exceptions.java:219)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.check(SqlProtoClient.java:198)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.executeSql(SqlProtoClient.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.executeSql(SqlProtoClient.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.executeSql(Connection.java:528)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeSqlImpl(PreparedStatement.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Statement.executeImpl(Statement.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:122)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:214)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.mysql.MySQLTable.doLock(MySQLTable.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.Table.lock(Table.java:254)

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat confused because the Flyway docs says that everything works on GAE with Cloud SQL and the AppEngineDriver. Maybe it's a recent change to either Flyway or GAE.

But here's my fix.

After using JAD to look at GAE's classes and also tracing Flyway, I think that some SQL statements such as LOCK are not supported by the RPC protocol used to send queries between an App Engine server instance and the MySQL cluster.

So on a whim, I've overridden MySQLTable.java in Flyway to use a simple Statement instead of a PreparedStatement. No statement caching but it works.

I just copied MySQLTable.java over to my project keeping the same packaging and replaced the following:

```
@Override
protected void doLock() throws SQLException
{
    jdbcTemplate.executeStatement("LOCK TABLES " + this + " WRITE");
}

@Override
protected void doUnlock() throws SQLException
{
    jdbcTemplate.executeStatement("UNLOCK TABLES");
}
```

executeStatement instead of execute.

We will be waiting for an official fix.

Regards,

Remy

Comment: The latest code already reverted to SELECT ... FOR UPDATE due to additional problems with LOCK TABLES. The next release should work out of the box again.